# Why does only one button appear when creating them inside a class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class that contains a single button and its constructor packs it onto the root window. Why does only one button get packed onto the window when multiple objects of this class are created? Shouldn't every object have its own button?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

class My_button:
    button = tk.Button(root, width=10, height=5)
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.button.pack()

button1 = My_button()
button2 = My_button()
button3 = My_button()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You defined the button at the class level, which is only ever executed once.

Comment: button1.pack() or button1.place() or button1.grid()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `button` outside of `__init__` so it is a class variable. That means it is shared by every instance of the class.

If you want each instance to have its own button, either inherit from `tk.Button` so that it *is a* button widget, or create the instance inside of `__init__`.

For more information see [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) in the official Python documentation.